# Python Saving JSON files one directory above python script directory

Tags: python

I've got an issue which i can not solve after long tries.

My python script is creating json files:

```
with open("/JSONs/teams_list.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(teams_list, file)
```

The directory where is my python script is:

```
~/Projects
```

In this Directory i have folder

```
~/Projects/JSONs
```

But my python does not want to save it there...

As well if i do like this:

with open("teams_list.json", "w") as file:
json.dump(teams_list, file)

It saves the JSON file one directory above /Projects so in my user folder.

The same issue is with reading files.

Comment: If you use `open("JSONs/teams_list.json", "w")` instead, does that solve your problem ? If so it is because you defined the path as absolute (starts with /) instead of relative.

Comment: It doesn't the same issue appears for that unfortunetly.

Comment: You can try using `pwd` in the JSONs folder then use the absolute path of the directory in your open function (with the file name appended of course).

Comment: What pwd will give here?

Comment: `pwd` is a UNIX command that returns the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute paths instead of relative paths.
Try this:

```
with open("JSONs/teams_list.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(teams_list, file)
```

Comment: It does not help